# Devices being filtered by Play Store as Not Compatible

Tags: android, aapt

From user feedback, Play is denying one of our Apps as "not compatible" with several devices. e.g:

- samsung galaxy s i90000
- HTC Desire HD A9191

I've done an aapt dump; here is the output:

```
sdkVersion:'4'
uses-permission:'android.permission.INTERNET'
uses-permission:'android.permission.CALL_PHONE'
uses-permission:'android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.telephony'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.telephony','requested a telephony-related
 permission or feature'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.touchscreen','assumed you require a touch
 screen unless explicitly made optional'
uses-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait'
uses-implied-feature:'android.hardware.screen.portrait','one or more activities
have specified a portrait orientation'
main
other-activities
other-receivers
other-services
supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large'
supports-any-density: 'true'
locales: '--_--'
densities: '160' '240'
```

Can anyone tell me which of these filters might be blocking those devices??

Comment: densities maybe? samsung galaxy is 233, desire 217

Comment: Hmm, could be... but "supports-any-density" is true, how do I go about supporting all densities?

Comment: yeah sorry read wrong line that's the correct setting